# Use Border in NativeScript for Android

Tags: android, html, css, typescript, nativescript

I wrote a NativeScript application and tested it with iOS. Now I wanted to try it out on Android and he is not using the borders properly. I want to use a Bordered-Label for a "Seperator" on a page.

For iOS the following Code is working out:

in my ts-file:

```
import { Border } from "ui/border";
```

in my html-file:

```
<label class="separator-label"></label>
```

in my css file:

```
.separator-label {
    border-bottom-color: rgba(255, 230, 0, 1);
    border-width: 1;
    margin-left: 10;
    margin-right: 10;
    margin-top: 20;
    margin-bottom: 20;
}
```

This is not displaying anything on Android. So I tried to use Borders according to the NativeScript Documentation:

ts-file:

```
import { Border } from "ui/border";
```

html-file:

```
<Border class="separator-border">
    <label class="separator-label"></label>    
</Border>
```

and also tried:

```
<Border borderWidth="1" border-Color="#FF0000" borderRadius="10">
    <label class="separator-label"></label>    
</Border>
```

css-file:

```
.separator-label {
    /*border-bottom-color: lightgrey;
    border-width: 1;*/
    margin-left: 10;
    margin-right: 10;
    margin-top: 30;
    margin-bottom: 30;
} 

.separator-border {
    border-width: 1;
    border-bottom-color: lightgray;
}
```

nothing was even visible, when I set some text into the label the text is displayed but without border. Did I forget something?

Comment: Did you try `border-bottom-width: 2;
    border-bottom-color: red;` And the Border element shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: yes I tried different width's and colors, nothing worked and there is also no exception occuring

Comment: Try inputting some text content into the label, see if the lack of text is what could be causing it.

Comment: Tried that too, it did not display text. But I actually found out, what might have caused the problem. I post an answer

Answer (score 0):

Actually it was quite easy to fix this. I recognized I was running `tns-core-modules 2.2.1`, so simply upgrading to 2.4 via

```
npm uninstall tns-core-modules

npm install tns-core-modules@2.4 --save
```

worked and then reinstall the platforms and you are ready to go.

Comment: Or just consider using/upgrading to 3+. Tons of fixes since 2.4. And 2.5 is the latest in the `2` major versions.

Comment: @pkanev Of course you are right, but we are working on a lot of beta-versions atm and need to upgrade the complete project in order to upgrade certain modules (since the dependencies require this). I would call it a very ... sensitive shape